# P2P resources searching

Tags: p2p

Recently I had an interest in decentralised network, and protocols enable and utilise it, like bittorrent.

However as I currently understand the protocol only gives a cryptic long hash for a given resource, file, video etc. and the trackers, and better DHTs, gives you the IPs of the devices that owns some of this resources to download from. But for this as I said one must povide a human unfriendly hash.

So, you cannot search by a keyword for a resource, like on networks that more http-ish. Google search etc. Even the torrent apis like Torrent Project, Strike project or any other torrent websites are not bittorrent protocol powered services. They are still just centralised services.

By that one conclusion is that, bittorrent depends on http, or centralised services and networks.

How is it possible to have a p2p protocol that gives the flexiblity of the current http accessed networks, services like, google, SO, etc. in terms of search for content over the network and still stay decentralized?

A web browser like browser app that connects over this protocol and can search resources by human inputable means like a google search with keywords and find peers by using DHTs or something specific to its own and download them.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)

Comment: Does Tor do the thing I describe? I think one does not download the files from another peer, peer as in the context of P2P.

Comment: I have no idea how it works. I'm just pointing you to something similar that you are looking into. p2p just means decentralized it doesn't mean file downloader.